# Google Sheets script - For loop - extra entry created?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This takes the number values from the cell C column, writing to column A with 1 row added to the final cell position. So 4 becomes A5, 26 becomes A27. 
But I always get cell 'A1' written and I can't figure out where it's from. Thanks in advance.

```
function HGP() {
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange('C2:C126');
var sourceRangeData = sourceRange.getValues()
for(var i=0;i<sourceRangeData.length;i++){
      var XX = "A" + (Number(sourceRangeData[i]) +1);
   sourceSheet.getRange(XX)
     .setValue('OK'); 
}
}
```

Comment: What's in C2 and column C?

Comment: I know that it is cheating but this ought to work. `var targetrange = sourceSheet.getRange('A3:A127');` `targetrange.setValues(sourceRangeData );` In any event, your code is very time consuming because it is using `.setValues" (a very time intensive command) within the loop.

Comment: Note that `sourceRangeData[i]` is an Array, not a value. So you are not correctly extracting the cell value to use as a number. (And please use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`! `Number(1)` and `1` are **not** the same thing!)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into both of your suggestions.

Comment: @tehhowch `Number(1) === 1//true`. If I'm not missing anything, Only `new Number()` creates a number object.. `Number(1)` should be equal to number literal 1 in all other cases.

Comment: Could someone point to an example of the best way to use 'setValues' in a case like this, thanks again : )

Comment: @Hiroto Kindly ask a new question with adequate information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue/Solution:

`C2:C126` has a empty cell somewhere. `Number(sourceRangeData[i])+1` becomes 0+1 and thus A1 gets written "OK". You can `filter` out the empty strings:

#### Snippet:

```
sourceSheet.getRangeList(
  sourceRange.getValues()
    .filter(String)
    .map(function(e,i){return 'A'+(parseInt(e[0])+1)})
).setValue('OK')
```

#### References:

- [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeList(String))
- [Array#Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: It was empty cells.. I will look into using the filtering.
Many thanks!